# SQS triggering lambda without stopping it first

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers, timeout, amazon-sqs

SQS won't stop the current execution of lambda before the next trigger and it is causing for the lambda to be timed out

I have a use case where I have 100 concurrent lambdas running, which are triggered from sqs. In the case of lambda i can only set the timeout to 15 minutes.

In the case of sqs triggers on lambdas, When anyone of the 100 lambdas I have currently running completes its execution, it should stop and sqs should start a new lambda whom execution starts from zero minutes but what I have observed is that it never stops the completed execution lambda and sqs give the next batch to it. So after some time it starts failing due to timeout.

Is there any way where we can stop the execution of lambda on complete so the sqs trigger the new lambda from start?

Comment: It does not work like that. One batch = one lambda execution.

Comment: Have you looked at SQS batch size and Lambda function concurrent limit options? It sounds like you want to serialize the processing of these events so set both to 1. Or use a FIFO batch where every message has the same group ID and they're processed in batches of 1.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are more details on how SQS consumers work.

[As stated by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html):

> Immediately after a message is received, it remains in the queue. To prevent other consumers from processing the message again, Amazon SQS sets a visibility timeout, a period of time during which Amazon SQS prevents other consumers from receiving and processing the message. The default visibility timeout for a message is 30 seconds. The minimum is 0 seconds. The maximum is 12 hours.

So instead of setting a timeout for lambda, set the visibility timeout for the SQS queue which can be set to 12 hours max. Also delete the message from the queue after the processing is done, if you do not want that to be processed again.